# How do I save Entity with WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

What is the best practice for saving an entity in wcf. I am calling my service through asp.net mvc site.

I have declared my context in the .svc file, as I would with normal winforms development.

```
    public ScoolEntities database = new ScoolEntities();
```

Then I am using the following to get the data by id.

```
 public student  GetStudentsById(int id)
    {

        var q  = (from mystudent in database.students where mystudent.id == id select mystudent);

        return q.ToList()[0]; 
    }
```

Then Finally I have a public save method

```
 public bool savechanges()
   {
       database.SaveChanges();
       return true;
   }
```

Then in my controller I have

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id=0)
    {

        return View(obj.GetStudentsById(id));
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MvcApplication1.ServiceReference1.student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)



            obj.savechanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return View();
    }
```

But it does not appear to save the changes and also what do I need to place in the return view I would have thought I call the GetStudents again but it does not appear to work?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Entity to the Context and need to call SaveChanges method.

```
database.Students.Add(student);
database.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What do i pass back from the edit post to enable the save of the form values?

Comment: What I mean is how to I pass my modified student back to the save changes method